# Creating GridView custom cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I have `Winforms` application and `Telerik GridView`.

All i want to achieve is custom creating custom cells and add `PregressBar` into  `Cell GridView` so i found [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-cells-custom-cells.html) tutorial that explain how to do that but since i am very new developer it's hard for me to understand how to use this in order to implementation this.

All i do is create this 2 classes: `ProgressBarCellElement` and `ProgressBarColumn` so i ask you if you can help me with that.
I know that this is not usual to ask this kind of questions but i did all can and still i don't know how to use it.

Update:

This os what i have try (not working):

```
private void radGridView1_CreateCell(object sender, GridViewCreateCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CellType == typeof(GridDataCellElement))
    {
        GridViewDataColumn dataColumn = e.Column as GridViewDataColumn;
        if (dataColumn.UniqueName == "Progress")
        {
            e.CellType = typeof(ProgressBarColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i already did it but sometimes it take several days until they answer, any way it's only a question how to use a code example and as i mention since i am very new developer it's hard for me to do that

Comment: Try working it out on you own and coming back here with a specific question regarding your posted code.

Comment: I only created this 2 classes in the example but if i add item to my GridView in the regular way i cannot see any ProgressBar, i am totally lost

Comment: winforms doesn't support custom stuff. use WPF instead.

Comment: I am using Tekerik which support custom

Comment: This is a specific third party library implementation question. I think you have greater chance on asking this on their forum

Comment: @HighCore this is absolutely not true

Comment: @checho and yet you've provided an answer that implies the use of a **$1000 US dollars** third party component, which, basically, proves my point. You can achieve the same in current technologies if you leave dinosaur winforms behind to rot in hell like it deserves and then it'll cost **$0** and a couple of lines of XAML (which can be written in 5 minutes, as opposed to the horrendous gigantic gargantuan behemoth amount of vomit inducing retarded hacks you need in winforms to do anything).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. This is the main form.

```
Public Partial Class Form1
Inherits Form

Private radGridView1 As RadGridView
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    radGridView1 = New RadGridView()
    Me.Controls.Add(radGridView1)
    radGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

    Dim textCol As New GridViewTextBoxColumn("Name")
    radGridView1.Columns.Add(textCol)

    Dim ageCol As New GridViewDecimalColumn("Age")
    radGridView1.Columns.Add(ageCol)

    Dim prgsCol As New ProgressBarColumn("Progress")
    radGridView1.Columns.Add(prgsCol)

    radGridView1.Rows.Add("Steve", 21, 15)
    radGridView1.Rows.Add("John", 43, 90)

    radGridView1.Rows.Add("Mike", 23, 66)
End Sub
End Class
```

This is the progress bar cell.

```
Class ProgressBarCellElement
Inherits GridDataCellElement
Private radProgressBarElement As RadProgressBarElement

Public Sub New(column As GridViewColumn, row As GridRowElement)
    MyBase.New(column, row)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub CreateChildElements()
    MyBase.CreateChildElements()

    radProgressBarElement = New RadProgressBarElement()
    Me.Children.Add(radProgressBarElement)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub SetContentCore(value As Object)
    If Me.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Value <> DBNull.Value Then
        Me.radProgressBarElement.Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(Me.Value)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property ThemeEffectiveType() As Type
    Get
        Return GetType(GridDataCellElement)
    End Get
End Property

Public Overrides Function IsCompatible(data As GridViewColumn, context As Object) As Boolean
    Return TypeOf data Is ProgressBarColumn AndAlso TypeOf context Is GridDataRowElement
End Function
End Class
```

And this is the progress bar column.

```
Public Class ProgressBarColumn
Inherits GridViewDataColumn
Public Sub New(fieldName As String)
    MyBase.New(fieldName)
End Sub

Public Overrides Function GetCellType(row As GridViewRowInfo) As Type
    If TypeOf row Is GridViewDataRowInfo Then
        Return GetType(ProgressBarCellElement)
    End If
    Return MyBase.GetCellType(row)
End Function
End Class
```